# How do I use this mutable reference of a struct in a loop spawning async tasks without having to use the Copy/Clone traits?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, memory, rust-tokio

I'm currently building a simple in-memory database to get back into 'learning' rust, but for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out a work around for what I'm trying to do.

I'm using tokio for asynchronous io/networking.

Here's the code:

```
let mut cache = Cache {
    buffer: vec![0; allocated],
    mapping: HashMap::new()
};

let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:9055").await?;

loop {
    let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        process_client(&mut cache, &mut socket).await?;
        Ok::<_, io::Error>(())
    });
}
```

Definition of the Cache struct:

```
struct Cache {
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
    mapping: HashMap<String, (usize, usize)>
}
```

Now the error I keep getting is this:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `cache`
   --> src\main.rs:172:22
    |
162 |       let mut cache = Cache {
    |           --------- move occurs because `cache` has type `Cache`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
172 |           tokio::spawn(async move {
    |  ______________________^
173 | |             process_client(&mut cache, &mut socket).await?;
    | |                                 ----- use occurs due to use in generator
174 | |             Ok::<_, io::Error>(())
175 | |         });
    | |_________^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

How can I pass a mutable reference of `cache` to the `process_client()` method in this async task without having to clone/copy the entire `cache` struct? (since cloning/copying would be a huge performance hit if the buffer was large)

I've tried to implement lifetimes, but I do not have a good understanding of lifetimes and how to use them properly.

Comment: Did you read about `Arc` and `Mutex`? That can be good start to read https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html

Comment: @ĐorđeZeljić In async context you want to use an async mutex. E.g. tokio has [`tokio::sync::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

Comment: @cdhowie That is not generally true: "Contrary to popular belief, it is ok and often preferred to use the ordinary Mutex from the standard library in asynchronous code."

Comment: @drewtato So does tokio do some trickery to keep a sync mutex from blocking a task thread, or...?

Comment: @cdhowie no, it's simply that most uses of mutexes aren't locked very often or for very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some form of synchronisation this cannot be done. This is by design, the compiler is preventing you from a potential race condition. Consider the case where tokio is running on multiple threads, the spawn gets hit and deferred to a different thread, the loop then repeats and the second spawn is hit and deferred to a different thread. You now have two mutable references to `cache` on two different threads, with potentially concurrent accesses.

To solve this you can use something like `Mutex`, in this case you should use `tokio::sync::Mutex` (or `RwLock` if you ever only need immutable borrows), along with an `Arc` (as otherwise there is no way to ensure that `cache` will live long enough and allow multiple valid references to it). For example:

```rust
let mut cache = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Cache {
    buffer: vec![0; allocated],
    mapping: HashMap::new()
}));
// ...
tokio::spawn({
    let cache = cache.clone();
    async move {
        process_client(&mut cache.lock().await, &mut socket).await?;
        // ...
    }
});
```